# microphone does not work

Tags: microphone

I use LINUX   UBUNTU    18.04  LTS.
The microphone of my headset is not recognized by any application.
So far I have tried the following:

1 settings / sound 
2 pulse audio volume control
3 terminal: alsamixer

4.
terminal
1. subl /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
2. options snd-hda-intel model= ,dell-headset-multi
3. Save

5.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yx33W-c4Cmg
install :   alsa-tools-gui 
run :  hdajackretask

After all these steps the problem still persists.
Can you please give me some advises how to solve this problem?
Thank you very much in advance!